# What does "Ich schlafe dabei fast immer im Sessel ein." mean?

Tags: adverb

I am a german learning student and I couldn't figure out what "dabei" means in this sentence.

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? Which of the possible meanings of "dabei" do you know?

Comment: Beim Fernsehen, beim Teetrinken, beim Sex - je nach dem, was Du im Sessel tust.

Answer (score 2):

*"dabei"* means *"bei dieser Sache"* ("while doing something" or "while something is happening"). The most likely candidate in this context would be *"beim Fernsehen"* ("while watching TV").